# Dimensions of soccer pitch

Tags: football, english-premier-league, la-liga, mls

I have seen that soccer fields vary in size. However, I believe there must be an agreed upon dimension for professional fields (Premier League, La Liga, MLS, etc.) What are these dimensions??

Either feet, yards, or meters works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the picth is not evenly in every field. There are maximum and minimun size.

`Law 1` told us about it:

**Dimensions**
*The touchline must be longer than the goal-line.*

*Length (touchline):*

minimum 90m (100yds)

maximum 120m (130yds)

*Length (goal-line):*

minimum 45m (50yds)

maximum 90m (100yds)

**Dimensions for international matches**

*Length (touchline):*

minimum 100m (100yds)

maximum 110m (120yds)

*Length (goal-line):*

minimum 64m (70yds)

maximum 75m (80yds)

Competitions may determine the length of the goal-line and touchline within the above dimensions.

---

There is no rule about that the pitch has to maintain some aspect. in fact a field can be **90m X 45m** or **90m X 89m**, but the last one would be a very strange field.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_pitch) that there is only a required range for the dimensions.

From my experience, I believe that even in professional leagues like the premier league, certain pitches do indeed have different dimensions and it can be an important influence on the game.

Comment: welcome to the site, while answering any question try checking if it's duplicate or not. And if you have any sources for premier league it will make this answer certainly more valuable.

Comment: Lol my premier league source is basically Fifa 15 which isn't necessarily reputable, but they do make a big point of pitches having different sizes

Comment: search in google for premier league pitch dimensions and you will get plenty of sources.

Comment: Well yes of course, but I thought I'd leave that to the author of the question